# Invisible reCaptcha: can't make a working AJAX call, getting infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-loop, invisible-recaptcha

The form had a JS validation and worked OK. Then I had to implement invisible reCaptcha with working validation.
The code looks like this:
**index.html**

```
//In the head I've

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=initRecaptcha&render=explicit"></script>

//then form comes

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="myForm" class="callback">                                    
    <div class="inputs">
        <label class="input input-name required">
            <span class="placeholder">Name</span>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </label>
        <label class="input input-phone required">
            <span class="placeholder">Phone</span>
            <input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="12">
        </label>
        <label class="input input-mail">
            <span class="placeholder">Email</span>
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="check">
        <label>
            <input class="check-agree" type="checkbox" name="agree" checked="checked" value="1">
            <span class="label">I agree <span class="agree-text js-agree-text">with terms and conditions</span></span>
        </label>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="submit-wrapper">
        <label class="submit">
            <input class="submit-form-button js-submit-form" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </label>            

   </div>       
    <div id="form-recaptch"></div>
</form>


//and in the end
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/form.js"></script>
```

the **form.js** comes next:

```
var submit_form_outer;

var initRecaptcha = function(){
    if ( document.getElementById("form-recaptch") ) {

        recaptcha = grecaptcha.render("form-recaptch", {
            'sitekey' : 'code',
            'theme'    : 'dark',            
            'badge'    : 'inline',
            'size'     : 'invisible',
            'callback' : submit_form_outer
        });
    }
}

$(function () {        

    $('.callback').submit(function (e) {
        submit_form($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
        /*stop refresh*/
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    /*More Functions*/

    function validateEmail(form) {
        var email = form.find('[name="email"]');
        var re = /.+@.+\..+/g;
        if( re.test(email.val()) || email.val() === ""){
            return true;
        } else {
            email.closest('.input').addClass('error');
            return false;
        }
    }
    function hasErrors (form) {
        var required = form.find('.required');
        var has_errors = false;
        required.each(function(){
            if(!$(this).find('input').val()){
                $(this).addClass('error');
                has_errors = true;
            }
        });
        return has_errors;
    }


    function submit_form() {

        if( hasErrors($("form#myForm")) || !validateEmail($("form#myForm"))){
            return false;
        }
    grecaptcha.execute();

    var container = $("#form-recaptch").parents("form");

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: container.serialize(),

        success: function (responseObj) {
                container.submit();                
                $('#myForm input').val('');
                $('#myForm textarea').val('');                            
                $('#status').html(responseObj);                             
        },
        error: function (xhr, error) {
          console.debug(xhr); 
          console.debug(error);
          $("#status").html("Failed.");
        },        

    });        
    }

    submit_form_outer = submit_form;

    function Form () {
        /*...*/


        /*More Functions*/
        $('.form').on('click', '.js-agree-text', function () {
            showAgreeBox();
            openFormPanel();
            return false;
        });

        $('.form').on('click', '.js-no-agree', function () {
            agreeNo();
            return false;
        });


        $('.form').on('click', '.js-yes-agree', function () {
            agreeYes();
            return false;
        });

        $('.check-agree').change(function() {
            var form = $(this).closest('.form');
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                form.find('.js-submit-form').removeClass('disabled');
            } else {
                form.find('.js-submit-form').addClass('disabled');
            }

        }
        /*More Functions*/
        this.callback = function () {

            showThankBox();
            openFormPanel();

            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);

        }

    }
    var mainform = new Form ();
});
```

And the **ajax.php**  with phpMailer:

```
<?php
$captcha;

if ( isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) ) {
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}

if( !$captcha ){
    $response = array (
        'status' => 'error',
        'info' => 'Please check the the captcha form.'
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
}


$secretKey = "key";

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$fields = array(
        'secret'    =>  $secretKey,
        'response'  =>  $captcha,
        'remoteip'  =>  $ip
    );
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    $responseKeys = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);


if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
    $response = array (
        'status' => 'spam',
        'info' => 'You look like a spam.'
    );

    echo '<span style="color:red;">'.json_encode($response).'</span>';
    exit;
} else {

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';    

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    if(!$mail->send()) 
    {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Message has been sent successfully";
    }   



}

?>
```

So, the problem is that CAPTCHA doesn't even check the form.
For instance I have another website where configuration is pretty simillar but with other validation, so each time I press submit button the images of CAPTCHA are shown and I should pass the test.
In this case nothing is shown. Only `{"status":"error","info":"Please check the the captcha form."}` message does appear which says that CAPTCHA test is skipped and not executed.

I want to keep the working form validation and make everything work together.
Any modifications/optimizations are welcome.

**UPDATE**:  This is new **form.js** code, now I'm getting infinte loops somewhere between `success: function` and the input **validation** has stopped working:

```
var submit_form_outer;

var initRecaptcha = function(){
    if ( document.getElementById("form-recaptcha") ) {

        recaptcha = grecaptcha.render("form-recaptcha", {
            'sitekey' : '',
            'theme'    : 'dark',
            'type'     : 'image',
            'badge'    : 'inline',
            'size'     : 'invisible',
            'callback' : submit_form_outer
        });
    }
}

$(function () {      

    submit_form_outer = submit_form; 

    $('.callback').submit(function (e) {        
        submit_form($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
        /*stop refresh*/        
    /*    e.stopPropagation();*/
    });



    var phone = $('[name="phone"]'),
        input = $('input[type="text"], textarea');



    phone.click(function () {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('error');
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $(this).val('+');
        }
    });
    phone.focusout(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length < 2) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });

    phone.bind("change keyup input click", function() {
        if (this.value.match(/[^0-9+ ]/g)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9+ ]/g, '');
        }
    });

    input.focus(function () {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('error');
        $(this).parent().find('span').addClass('focused');
    });
    input.focusout(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).parent().find('span').removeClass('focused');
        }
    });

    function validateEmail(form) {
        var email = form.find('[name="email"]');
        var re = /.+@.+\..+/g;
        if( re.test(email.val()) || email.val() === ""){
            return true;
        } else {
            email.closest('.input').addClass('error');
            return false;
        }
    }
    function hasErrors (form) {
        var required = form.find('.required');
        var has_errors = false;
        required.each(function(){
            if(!$(this).find('input').val()){
                $(this).addClass('error');
                has_errors = true;
            }
        });
        return has_errors;
    }


    function submit_form() {

        if( hasErrors($("form#myForm")) || !validateEmail($("form#myForm"))){
            return false;
        } 


    var container = $("#form-recaptcha").parents("form");


    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: container.serialize(),

        success: function (responseObj, textStatus, xhr) {                            

            console.log('success');
            console.log(responseObj);

            container.submit();                 
            $('#myForm textarea').val('');                            
            $('#status').html(responseObj);

           /*if(xhr.status === '200'){
                $("#status").html('200');               
            }
            else{
                console.log('else');
                grecaptcha.reset();
            }*/         

        },
        error: function (xhr, error) {      
          console.log('error');     
          console.debug(error);
          console.debug(xhr);           
          $("#status").html("Failed.");
          grecaptcha.reset();
        },        

    });
        grecaptcha.reset();
    }



    function Form () {

        function openFormPanel () {
            $('body').addClass('form-panel-opened form-panel-close-callback');
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
        }
        function closeFormPanel () {
            $('body').removeClass('form-panel-opened');
            $('.button-menu').removeClass('active');
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('body').removeClass('form-panel-close-callback');
                $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
            }, 700);
        }

        function showAgreeBox () {
            $('.form .agreement-box').addClass('show');
            $('.form .thank-box').removeClass('show');
            $('.agreement .scrollable').scrollTop(0);
        }
        function showFormBox () {
            $('.form .agreement-box').removeClass('show');
            $('.form .thank-box').removeClass('show');
        }
        function showThankBox () {
            $('.form .agreement-box').removeClass('show');
            $('.form .thank-box').addClass('show');
        }

        function agreeYes(){
            if($('body').hasClass('fp-viewing-2')){
                closeFormPanel();
            } else {
                showFormBox();
            }
            $('.js-submit-form').removeClass('disabled');
            $('.check-agree').prop('checked', true);
        }
        function agreeNo(){
            if($('body').hasClass('fp-viewing-2')){
                closeFormPanel();
            } else {
                showFormBox();
            }
            $('.js-submit-form').addClass('disabled');
            $('.check-agree').prop('checked', false);
        }


        $('.form').on('click', '.js-agree-text', function () {
            showAgreeBox();
            openFormPanel();
            return false;
        });

        $('.form').on('click', '.js-no-agree', function () {
            agreeNo();
            return false;
        });


        $('.form').on('click', '.js-yes-agree', function () {
            agreeYes();
            return false;
        });

        $('.check-agree').change(function() {
            var form = $(this).closest('.form');
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                form.find('.js-submit-form').removeClass('disabled');
            } else {
                form.find('.js-submit-form').addClass('disabled');
            }
        }).mouseover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        });

        $('.form').on('click', '.js-submit-form', function () {
            var form = $(this).closest('.form');
            var agree = form.find('.check-agree').prop('checked');
            if(!agree) return false;
        });     

        $('.form').on('click', '.js-submit-form', function () {
            if( !hasErrors($("form#myForm")) ||       validateEmail($("form#myForm"))){
            if ( grecaptcha.getResponse() !== 0 ) {
                grecaptcha.execute(); 
            }   
        } 

    });

        function resetForm () {
            $('.form input[type="text"], .form textarea').each(function () {
                $(this).val('');
            });
            $('.form .placeholder').removeClass('focused');


        }

        this.callback = function () {

            showThankBox();
            openFormPanel();
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);

        }
    }
    var mainform = new Form ();
});
```

Comment: I can suggest you a little hint, not related to recapcha:
1) add a hidden by CSS field. If it's filled in - you have a bot in front of you, so forwrad it to appropriate page.
2) use fingerprint.js to store the data of active users. If fingerprint of incoming user already  submitted form and marked as bot - forward him away. A bit faster and sometimes more efficient than recapcha....

Comment: Thank you! I will leave it for the future project. Now I want to find the solution for this problem in order to find the error.

Comment: Try the Google reCaptcha library, for an aexample [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582439/recaptcha-v3-cross-browser)

Comment: you can remove this validation after it's valid by your first try, so you can use that as workarround.

Comment: **episch**, could you please provide example?

Comment: I had to remove the `container.submit();` and it seems to work :) The only issue left, that I want to fire captcha test once form won't have any errors. But I haven't succeded with this code: `$('.form').on('click', '.js-submit-form', function () {
   if( !hasErrors($("form#myForm")) || validateEmail($("form#myForm"))){
    if ( grecaptcha.getResponse() !== 0 ) {
     grecaptcha.execute(); 
    } 
   } 
   
  });`

Comment: If you solved the problem, please create an Answer below and mark it as such for future users.  [Stack Overflow is not a Forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after long digging, I've found that the problem was in the `success` method. More exactly I've placed `container.submit();` in it, and it was the issue which caused the infinite looping.
    So, the final **form.js** looks like:

```
var submit_form_outer;


var initRecaptcha = function(){
    if ( document.getElementById("form-recaptcha") ) {

        recaptcha = grecaptcha.render("form-recaptcha", {
            'sitekey' : '6',
            'theme'    : 'dark',
            //'type'     : 'image',
            'badge'    : 'inline',
            'size'     : 'invisible',
            'callback' : submit_form_outer
        });
    }
}

$(function () {      

    submit_form_outer = submit_form; 

    $('.callback').submit(function (e) {        
        submit_form($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    /*some functions*/

    function validateEmail(form) {
        var email = form.find('[name="email"]');
        var re = /.+@.+\..+/g;
        if( re.test(email.val()) || email.val() === ""){
            return true;
        } else {
            email.closest('.input').addClass('error');
            return false;
        }
    }
    function hasErrors (form) {
        var required = form.find('.required');
        var has_errors = false;
        required.each(function(){
            if(!$(this).find('input').val()){
                $(this).addClass('error');
                has_errors = true;
            }
        });
        return has_errors;
    }       


    function Form () {

        /*more functions and validations*/

        $('.form').on('click', '.js-submit-form', function () {
            var form = $(this).closest('.form');
            var agree = form.find('.check-agree').prop('checked');

            if ((!agree) || ( hasErrors($("form#myForm")) || !validateEmail($("form#myForm"))))         
                return false;
            else {
                if ( grecaptcha.getResponse() !== 0 ) {
                    grecaptcha.execute(); 
                }   
            }
        });     


        function resetForm () {
            $('.form input[type="text"], .form textarea').each(function () {
                $(this).val('');
            });
            $('.form .placeholder').removeClass('focused');


        }


    }

    function submit_form() {

        if( hasErrors($("form#myForm")) || !validateEmail($("form#myForm"))){
            return false;
        } 


        var container = $("#form-recaptcha").parents("form");


        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: container.serialize(),

            beforeSend: function(e) {

                $("#status").html("working...");
            },
            success: function (responseObj, textStatus, xhr) {                            

                $('#myForm').trigger("reset");
                $('#status').html('sent');
                showThankBox();
                grecaptcha.reset();        

            },
            error: function (responseObj, xhr, error) { 
              $("#status").html("error.");
              grecaptcha.reset();
            },        

        });
            grecaptcha.reset();
    }   

    var mainform = new Form ();
});
```